# Miter joint problem in terrace

Tags: rot, miter

I need to repair a separated miter joint on a terrace that has now begun to show signs of wood rot after two years.
[image]
[image]
The location experiences significant humidity fluctuations due to its proximity to the coast. It also receives intense sunlight during the summer and gets wet when it rains.
My question is, how would you fix this joint to make it last as much as possible?
I'm considering a couple of options. A small and cheap repairment would be to clean and fill the gap with some kind of elastic wood filler, and then sand and paint.
The other option is to remove all rotten pieces and put new ones, but if I do that, will it not separate again as it is now?
Additionally I don't know what to do to to seal the vertical post with the flat wood around.
I'm quite lost here as I don't have much experience in outdoors fixings, any advice about a technique or best product to use will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sun and rain will cause significant wood expansion and contraction.

As it is now, someone used the wrong filler and did not do a good job at it.

A UV resistant silicone filler could do the job.

You could also consider this product

[image: asphalt]